# How to handle multiple css file in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a varsity project I need to design a personal website with only html,css and javascript. One of the tasks was, It will have a button,clicking on that button will change the design of the whole website each time. I successfully designed the website with a button and 3 different css files. Whenever I click the button it changes from style1.css to style2.css to style3.css as I wanted. My default css on every page was style1.css

```
<link id="change" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
```

Thus, whenever I click some other menu buttons,It goes to its default design of style1.css.But I need to stay in that particular design(particular css file) even if I refresh any page.

The menu button that changes design:

```
<li><a id="btn" onClick="swap()" href="#">Style 1</a></li>
```

The javascript code I used to changed between css files.

```
var flag=0;
function swap(){
    if(flag==0){
        document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML=" Style 2";
        document.getElementById('change').setAttribute('href', 'css/style2.css');
        flag=1;
    }
    else if(flag==1)
    {
        document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML=" Style 3";
        document.getElementById('change').setAttribute('href', 'css/style3.css');
        flag=2;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML=" Style 1";
        document.getElementById('change').setAttribute('href', 'css/style1.css');
        flag=0;
    }
}
```

If you have any question please ask. Remember, I can use only HTML,CSS and Javascript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Cookies to remember which style sheet to use.

Comment: Yes, use cookies or local storage to track state :)